# Deleting files when creating a Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

One of the tips Burt Beckwith provides when creating plugins is to delete files you don't use. 
So if you don't use UrlMappings.groovy - delete it. 
I was wondering about directories.  If you have no controllers, should you delete the controller directory?

Thanks

Comment: You might not know it, but Burt himself patrolling all or most of the grails plugin and deletes those unwanted directory to keep'em clean. :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "Yes, you should." Looking at some of the other plugins you can see this is pretty standard practice. For example the [Redis plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-redis/tree/master/grails-app) on GitHub.

Comment: You have all the resources at your finger tip. That is great. I hope you won't mind if I ask you some day about a resource. ;-)

Comment: More than happy to help if I can. Perhaps I will learn a few things along the way (my goal in helping out).

Answer (score 2):

You can delete directories, but they'll get re-created after running various scripts, in particular `package-plugin`. I tend to remove them as source folders in GGTS so they're not distracting - I like to only see directories that are being used. I used to use an Ant script to do various build tasks for plugins, but at this point all I use them for is the `post-package-cleanup` task that deletes unused folders, e.g .https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/build.xml.

It turns out that only three plugin files are required - all of the rest can be deleted if they're not used. These are the plugin descriptor, application.properties (although this is only used to specify the Grails version), and BuildConfig.groovy. BuildConfig.groovy might be optional too if you don't need to publish the plugin to a repo and have no dependencies. At a minimum it's needed to specify the release plugin, but if you don't need that they you can probably get by with just 2 files :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Good old Ant.  I watched your video on DZone yesterday as well. Good stuff.  Do you not think it would make more sense to change the package-plugin command somehow?  If so, how can this be done.